# getting a webpage's image(s) with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

Is there a way to get an image from an outer webpage with javascript code?

I'll explain:
I have a website, lets say www.one.com, and I want to show in this website's homepage an image that exists in another website, lets say www.two.co.il

Can I do it?

Comment: No, SOP shall not restrict in case of images.

Comment: Displaying images does work actually!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = "http://www.two.co.il/image.jpg";
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

Comment: That image file resource has to shared or else it will give Access denied I guess.

Comment: That is pretty self-explaining isn´t it? You cannot access anything that is not open for the public domain, can you?

Comment: @yogi — If it isn't shared, then the URL would be an HTTP Forbidden response and not an image.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I don't have the image full url, just the page's url

Comment: When you do not have the image´s url, how can anybody know what you want to display? Do you want to display just random images from a different page?

Comment: yes, I want to get an array with the page's images or just a random image

Comment: You should update your question then. Obviously everyone misunderstands you!

Answer (score 2):

A convenient thing is to create *first* a placeholder in your HTML:

```
<div id='externalImage'></div>
```

because it will not disrupt the function if the layout changes and allows precise placement.

As for the real question on how you put an image, assuming from the tags that you use Jquery:

```
$("#externalImage").html("<img src=\"http://put.url.here/image.jpg\" />");
```

if you want to insert it into the aforementioned placeholder. Otherwise to plainly add the image to the document you can append it to the documentd BODY or elsewhere using `document.body.appendChild` like in the other answers.

Comment: Why **not**? Because in real world applications there WILL be a placeholder, that can be previously skinned by CSS and avoids traversing the document, thus not disrupting its function if the layout changes. I bet appending to BODY is an unlikely case.

Comment: It is about adding an image to your website. Where to put that image is up to the author. Why do you ever want to estimate possibilities that are beyond the original question?

Comment: If someone´s asks you, how do I put an image on my page, your answer cannot be "create first a placeholder", because that is simply not true.

Comment: Because the OP talks about putting the image in a website's *homepage*. By fair judging, we can assume this homepage is not blank but populated, and the simplest and cleanest approach would be to have a placeholder, because it's a enormously common scenario.
I'll rephrase my post, but honestly I thing you're hitting a bit too hard on my solution which seems reasonable in real-life scenarios.

Comment: (Irony: I read now that the OP was asking for another thing, he has only the page URL non the image URL... talking about being clear...)

Comment: All I am saying is, when someone asks you "What is happening during rainy weather?", the answer is "You get wet!" and not "Take an umbrella with you!". But yeah, our discussion is kind of unnecessary :)

Comment: All I am saying is that I try to make sure that they don't use the umbrella upside-down (you won't get wet but it's a pain to hold it...). I've rephrased my answer, but I think that a bit of advice on common and good practices can be useful and purposeful - maybe my fault was not pointing out that part of the answer was a *suggeston* to add to the plain answer. We're here to share, after all.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
image.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.two.co.il/foo.jpeg');
image.setAttribute('alt', 'something suitable');
document.body.appendChild(image);
```

So long as you aren't trying to get content from the other site *into JS* (you aren't, you are create an img element in the DOM, JS has no further involvement), you won't run into the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I don't have the image full url, just the page's url

Comment: The same origin policy will prevent you parsing the HTML to find img elements to figure out the URI from.

Answer (score 1):

or simply:

```
$("<img src='" + imgUrl + "' alt='" + altText + "'>").appendTo("body");
```

Comment: +1 for jQuery, so that it'll work in all browsers. I'd go for a solution that doesn't rely on string concatenation, though, such as `.attr` or `$('<img />', { src: imgUrl, alt: altText })` but I guess that's mostly a matter of preference.

Comment: Appending to body has sense to show the general approach, which is 100% legit, but in real-world applications you will use most of the times a placeholder, 'cause appending to BODY doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Yes I agree with you @DavidHedlund, in some cases you might do that for accurate and safe coding, but sometimes when speed is a matter of coding, this approach would be better, also building the whole html and appending all of them at once is the most efficient solution.

Comment: @Cranio I wrote that code because the previous answers included that kind of approach. So I wrote it like that way. I would code it like you too.

Comment: Yes of course, I just wanted to expand on a right and correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

make a div and give id = "div1" with height and width

```
 <div id='div1' height='100' width='100'></div>
    $('#div1').css('background-image, 'http://www.two.co.il/urImage.jpg');
```

it is shortest way to apply image